# R: Calculating percentage of missing values in all subsequent columns based off of response to one column

Tags: r, na, percentage, completion

first time posting and looking for help to a question I haven't found.

I have a survey of > 100 questions. It's a dataset of ~1200, and I'd like to see the completion percentage of all following questions based off of the answer to one question (about 30 answers to that question so I don't think separate data frames is practical). A bit stuck on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Help us help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Crucial to your question is some sample data (not a photo, but the output of dput or a reprex you define yourself) and an example of the desired output.

Comment: If your data are called `data` and your variable of interest is called `var`, this should get you going in the right direction: `data %>% group_by(var) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~mean(!is.na(.x))))`